# Asking a person to forward a meeting invitation

Tags: professionalism

Is it correct to say "Please see below and Kindly forward to the appropriate person for participation"

I am sending invites for a meeting and I want the person who is going to receive the email to forward it to the relevant person so that they can participate

Comment: is your question about the wording, or about running a meeting when you don't actually know who should be at the meeting? Is the invite recipient in the same company as you? The same team? Please add more details about your situation and precisely what aspect of it you're asking about.

Comment: If you don't know who to invite, how do the people you send the invite to know who to invite?

Comment: My colleague had a conversation with the person I am sending an email to. I just wanted to know if the wording is correct

Answer (score 7):

If you don't know who the "relevant" person is, then yes.

Because how else are they going to know to join?

Answer (score 1):

I would advise not doing this as it can be received as being uninformed about the topic and the scope of the meeting.

Instead, my advice would be to get in touch with the one contact you have (preferably in person) and ask their opinion on who might be interested in the meeting.

After getting the contact information, **you** have the choice who will be invited, assuming you know who are the stakeholders, which should be part of the preparations of your meeting.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your forward notice suficies. However, an addition that would work could be a reminder that if they no longer want to receive emails like this to let you know.

Example:

> Please forward to anyone I’ve missed and likewise, let me know if you’d prefer not to receive these invites in the future.

Answer (score 1):

An effective meeting should be addressed to the people that can add value to it. Depending on proxies is a sign of a broken communication.

Before setting up the meeting, *call* the person who knows who should meet the meeting needs and then send the invitation.

That's the only effective way to ensure the proper people *receives* the invitation. Notice it does not guarantee, however, their attendance - to do so, a brief context about the meeting, its goals and the reason why this people should join are recommended.